# Remove Part of an array mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi i am attmepting to remove anything after the first value e.g.

Collection:{

```
"_id' :.....
"UrlId" : "5dfc1aa2986b7c30f3398be4",
    "coverInput" : 
           [
            "https://test.com/s/files/1/00351576213050",
            "https://test.com.au"
           ],
```

}

what I want to replace the document with is:

Collection:{

```
"_id' :.....
"UrlId" : "5dfc1aa2986b7c30f3398be4",
    "coverInput" : 
           [
            "https://test.com/s/files/1/00351576213050"
           ],
```

}

Im sure this is something simple. I tried this but got an error:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        coverInput: { $substr: [ "$coverInput", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$coverInput", "," ] } ] }
    }
}
]).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { coverInput: doc.coverInput } } ) )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$substr` operator is used to work with strings. You have to use Aggregation array operators to work with array fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "coverInput": {
      "$slice": ["$coverInput", 1]
    }
  }}
])
```

Or if you want to update the document

```
db.test.updateOne(
  { _id: doc._id },
  [{
    $set: { coverInput: { "$slice": ["$coverInput", 1] } }
  }]
)
```